# Matching strings with abbreviations; fuzzy matching

Tags: r, string, stringr, fuzzy, stringdist

I am having trouble matching character strings. Most of the difficulty centers on abbreviation

I have two character vectors. I am trying to match words in vector A (typos) to the closes match in vector B.

```
vec.a <- c("ce", "amer", "principl")

vec.b <- c("ceo", "american", "principal")
```

My first crack at this was by using **stringdist** package fuzzy matching command. However, I can only push it so far.

```
amatch(vec.a, vec.b, maxDist = 3)
[1] 1 1 3
```

The amatch/fuzzy matching works wonderful for typos: in this case, **ce -> ceo** and **principl -> principal**. The problem arises with abbreviations. **amer** should be matched with **american**, but **ce** is a closer match--on account that less permutations are needed to match.
How can I deal with fuzzy matching under the presence of abbreviations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the dissimilarity measure to the Jaro distance or Jaro-Winkler
distance works for the example provided in your question.

```r
library(stringdist)

vec.a <- c("ce", "amer", "principl")
vec.b <- c("ceo", "american", "principal")

amatch(vec.a, vec.b, maxDist = 1, method = "jw", p = 0) # Jaro
#> [1] 1 2 3
amatch(vec.a, vec.b, maxDist = 1, method = "jw", p = .2) # Jaro-Winkler
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you. Still, when I tried it with my data only 55% of my data got matched. The rest was NA. I know that there should be way more matches. Is there any way I could spruce those matching numbers a little bit higher?

Comment: That is hard to say without knowing your data. Can you add a few of those cases where it fails to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `agrep` is what the question is asking for.

```r
vec.a <- c("ce", "amer", "principl")
vec.b <- c("ceo", "american", "principal")

sapply(vec.a, \(x){
    out <- agrep(x, vec.b)
    ifelse(length(out) > 0L, out, 0L)
})
#>       ce     amer principl 
#>        1        2        3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>